# How to detect iphone shake gesture one time !

Tags: iphone, shake

hi i want iphone detect shake gesture only one time .

after iphone had been shaken and html files showed , then i want  iphone doesn't detect  shake anymore .

here is my code :

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    {
        if (acceleration.x > kAccelerationThreshold 
            || acceleration.y > kAccelerationThreshold
            || acceleration.z > kAccelerationThreshold) {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the delegate:

```
[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = nil;
```

Comment: Would it not be better to stop the accelerometer when you don't need it anymore?